# Magento installation time i got the following error about mcrypt and curl

Tags: php

Following errors occur:

- PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.
- PHP extension "curl" must be loaded.

I was trying to remove extension=php_mcrypt.dll in php.in, but the problem is still present.

Comment: did you restart your apache?

Comment: yes, I also try but not solved that errors.